# Select a tag from multiline html code using preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all, multilinestring

I want to use the php function preg_match_all to find a part of the html code to replace it by another one.

This is what I need to find:

```
<attachfiles>
tag{link} attr{rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"} 
sources{
file1.css,
file2.css
}
</attachfiles>
```

I made a regular expression that find it but only if that code is present once into the entire html.

My regular expression is:

```
"|\<attachfiles\>(.*)\<\/attachfiles\>|s"
```

The issue comes out when I have the code to find repeated two or more times. Since the regular expression uses the |s operator (multiline), when I have the code more than one time it returns all the html code from the very first  to the vary last

For example:

```
<attachfiles>
tag{link} attr{rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"} 
sources{
file1.css,
file2.css
}
</attachfiles>

... html code ...
... html code ...

<attachfiles>
tag{script} attr{type="text/css" language="javascript"} 
sources{
file1.js,
file2.js
}
</attachfiles>
```

My regular expression in this case is returning ALL the code, from the first

```
<attachfiles> to the last </attachfiles>
```

including the

```
... html code ... 
... html code ...
```

that is between the code that I am searching for.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 0):

Use the DOM and create a `new DOMDocument()` then `loadHTML($html)` and do `getElementsByTagName('attachfiles')` then iterate through the `->length` with `->item(i)`, then do what you want.. `replaceChild` or whatever.

Comment: Thanks Topera for the link and Meder for your solution!.

Comment: I ve been reading the regular expression modificators and I solved the issue using a couple of them. Using "|\<attachfiles\>(.*)\<\/attachfiles\>|msU" worke perfect!. Thanks again!!